# Automatically delete files created by a library when it is killed

Tags: c++, linux, temporary-files

I have a Linux dynamic library that has to create temporary files. These files have to have a filename - they can't be created and immediately unlinked. I also can't intercept signals like `SIGINT` and `SIGKILL` because this is a library that is used by other programs.

Is there a sane way to have the files automatically deleted when the process that created them is killed?

**Clarifications:**

1. These really are my constraints. Please don't answer saying "you can `unlink()`" when I just said in the question that I can't `unlink()`.
2. I realise this will require OS support - obviously when my program is killed it can't then run any code *itself* to delete the files. But there may be some way to mark the files so that the OS deletes them.

For example Windows has a ["delete on close"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/delete-on-close) option which means when you program is killed any open files it has are closed and automatically deleted (I think; I've not tried it). Something like that is clearly possible in theory on Linux if such functionality exists somewhere. I just want to know whether it does.

Comment: Show some code please... as an [MCVE]

Comment: No code is necessary for this question.

Comment: That is your opinion.

Comment: Why do they have to keep filenames?

Comment: They're passed to LLVM and it only accepts input in the form of filenames (one day we can hopefully fix that but it is an enormous task).

Comment: LLVM should be mentioned in the question (not in comments)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, questions like "Why doesn't this code work?" must provide a MCVE. This question doesn't fit this pattern. LLVM is irrelevant, because interaction with any program that only accepts filenames would suffer from the same problem.

Comment: LLVM can read it from standard input, can it not?

Comment: LLVM is relevant, because it accepts filenames.

Comment: LLVM can't read from standard input, and LLVM *itself* is not relevant to the question. I'm not rearchitecting LLVM for this. I have clearly explained the constraints in the question.

Comment: File must have a name you say? Try `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fd>` after unlinking it. Not guaranteed to work in all cases though.

Comment: You can also have the library fork a watchdog process. Or if you are truly paranoid, two watchdog processes that watch the parent process *and*  each other.

Comment: @n.m.: You mean before, not after, right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you can do it before if you want, but it doesn't makes a lot of sense, because before unlinking the file would still be available under its original name and you could just use that instead.

Comment: @n.m. Uh never mind, I confused "using the `/proc/..` path" with "obtaining a handle to the file" in my mind :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file, then pass `/proc/self/fd/X` to LLVM where X is your file descriptor. You can now unlink it (as Basile suggests),

Since `/proc/self` disappears only when your program closes, the name and therefore the file lives long enough.

Comment: I think `/proc/self/fd/X` should be opened *before* unlinking

Comment: This so nearly works (for my purposes), but unfortunately my program has a lot of temporary files (like 5000), and `ulimit -n` is 1024 by default on most systems. Stupid Linux. Probably have to go with my answer. :-/

Comment: It's irrelevant when the file is unlinked, you can do it before or after starting the subprocess. What is important is that your process keeps the file open as long as the subprocess might want to use the `/proc/<PID>/fd/<FD>` path, because closing it removes that directory entry, AFAIK. BTW: Can that really use `self` as component in the path? One process' self is different from another's.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: The question is specifically talking about a library, which executes in-process. So yes, in that context `/proc/self` works.

Comment: True. I was under the impression that LLVM was started in a separate process by the library, but given the information present, that is not the case.

Answer (score 5):

While this is not particularly sane, Linux allows you to pass names of deleted files as well through /proc/$pid/fd/$number .

Comment: The first answer that doesn't actually ignore the question, thanks!

Comment: The files aren't deleted if you have opened a handle to them via this path. Files are deleted when no more links to them exist (including this one!)

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Linux dynamic library that has to create temporary files.

You could use [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) to register a handler which would delete all these temporary files at [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) time (or normal termination of `main`). Of course that won't work with signals.

You could create these files in some `tmpfs` filesystem. Then they would be deleted at shutdown.

If you follow some naming convention about these files, you could also publish your library with some cleaning script (triggered by some `crontab` entry).

> Is there a sane way to have the files automatically deleted when the process that created them is killed?

**Not in general** (and there cannot be one with POSIX file semantics). You might write a cleaning program (perhaps using [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities) to be run from outside (e.g. as a `crontab` job, or as some daemon).

You could also [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) each such temporary file after creation (with `open` or `creat`) and keep a file descriptor for it. Then, when the process is terminated, or when it `close`-s that file descriptor, the file resource are reclaimed. That trick is used by [tmpfile(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpfile.3.html).

BTW, if you use LLVM as a JIT-translator, you could consider using [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/). It is capable of generating code without any input file.

Such temporary files cannot be removed automagically, because some *other* process could open them (by their name) - at an arbitrary moment. And that is why Linux cannot have a "delete on close" (in contrast, Windows is rumored to let only a single process write a given file).

> But there may be some way to mark the files so that the OS deletes them.

No, not on Linux or POSIX. That feature should be provided by application code.

Comment: Yeah sadly that only works with *normal program termination* which doesn't get me anything more than RAII.

Comment: I can't `unlink()`. I said I need to keep the filename. And adding a cleaning script to `crontab` isn't really a sane solution for a library.

Comment: Then what do you suggest? I am trying to explain that your expectations are unreasonable (and what you want to achieve is impossible)

Comment: I expect an answer that either actually answers the question or gives some authoritative reasons why it isn't possible. If my constraints weren't real constraints then I wouldn't have put them in the question!

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot delete these after the program using your library is not running because the program using it it is no longer running.

Instead you should probably either

- Check for outdated/oversize/leftover temporary files in the normal operation of your library (cleaned by next run)
- Create a separate program that manages these for you (cleaned periodically)

This feels like a fairly common question (I've certainly had it), but it comes from a misunderstanding about what can happen to your program. `SIGKILL` will immediately terminate it outside of what your program can handle, and no further operations by it will be run. (a few special ones can continue running)

As [this post on the subject](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281439/why-should-i-not-use-kill-9-sigkill) puts it

> `SIGKILL` pulls the rug out from your running process, terminating it immediately.

Comment: Note that this is not obvious. On Windows, you _can_ delete files when your program stops running, even from a library. It's Linux which misses this feature.

Comment: Perhaps during normal termination, but there are always states outside of your control, such as power loss that cannot be handled in that manner.

Comment: Chances are pretty good that it would still work; Windows prefers to keep those files in cache as it knows they're not persistent. NTFS transaction logs are a second line of defense.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to `fork()` a child process. Then send all your temporary filenames to this process via some mechanism.

The child process can register to know when its parent is killed like this:

```
#include <sys/prctl.h>
int ret;
ret = prctl (PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGUSR1);
if (ret)
        perror ("prctl");
```

And then it will receive `SIGUSR1` when the parent is killed. At that point it can delete the files normally.